# Javascriptの関数の中で別の関数を呼び出すとき、関数名の右隣に括弧を付けない理由

Tags: javascript

10秒間のストップウォッチゲーム的なものを作っているプログラムなのですが、
以下javascriptで

```
var game = {
    startTime: null,
    displayArea: document.getElementById('display-area')
  };
  function start() {
    game.startTime = Date.now();
    document.body.onkeydown = stop;
    //stop()ではなく何故stop?
  }
  function stop() {
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var seconds = (currentTime - game.startTime) / 1000;
    if (9.5 <= seconds && seconds <= 10.5) {
      game.displayArea.innerText = seconds + '秒でした。すごい。';
    } else {
      game.displayArea.innerText = seconds + '秒でした。残念。';
    }
  }
  if (confirm('OKを押して10秒だと思ったら何かキーを押して下さい')) {
    start();
  }
```

markdownにも書いてあるように、その上のコードで、

```
document.body.onkeydown = stop;
```

とありますが、何故ここのstopはstop()としてはいけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`()` がついたものは関数呼び出しですが、 `()` がないものは関数自身を指します。

```
document.body.onkeydown = stop;
```

は `document.body.onkeydown` に `stop` を代入しています。

仮に

```
document.body.onkeydown = stop();
```

としてしまった場合は `document.body.onkeydown` に `stop関数の戻り値` を代入してしまうことになります。